# Find the number that appears the most in an array

Tags: c

I have been debugging this problem for one night but still have no idea what has gone wrong. Let's say I input an array of 6 numbers which is {100,150,150,200,200,250} since 150 and 200 appear the same number of time then output the smaller number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int  arr[20] = { NULL }, num, result;
    printf("Input a number(1-20) and enter a series of numbers in ascending order: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[k]);
    }
    int c1, c2, i, j;
    int temp = 0;
    j = result = 0;
    c1 = c2 = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= num-2; i++) {                /*Add c1 if the value is the same*/
        int a = arr[i];
        if (arr[i+1] == a) c1++;
        else {
            j = i + 1;
            temp = arr[j];
            while (1) {
                if (arr[j+1] == temp) {
                    c2++;
                    j++;
                }
                else break;
            }
        }
        if (c2 > c1) {                  /*Move i to the position after j*/
            c1 = 0;
            result = temp;
        }   
        if ((c2 < c1) || (c2 == c1)) {  /*Move j to the next position*/
            result = a;
            c2 = 0;
        }
        i = j + 1;
    }
    printf("Number that appears the most time:%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

**Will edit everytime after I did some progress**
This is what I have done so far. 
The output is correct for {100,150,150,200,200,250} but now the loop is stuck if I input a larger array with 8 numbers {100,100,100,150,150,200,250,300}. Help@@

Comment: Question. Is there a defined range for the numbers the user will enter? For example, are the numbers held in `arr` limited to a certain range? E.g., 0-1000? The can open a whole new simplified approach to answering this type question. If the range is reasonable, you can simply use a *Frequency Array* to map occurrences of a number to an index.

Comment: Yes,range is from 1-20 I know how to solve the problem with frequency array, i'm just trying different approach here.

Comment: OK, but you enter `1-20` to determine the number of elements the user enters. I'm asking about the range of the numbers that go in `arr[0], arr[1], ...` If the range is fixed, say `0-1000`, then declare `int freq[1000] = {0};` (note: your `{ NULL }` is incorrect). Then you will loop over the numbers in `arr` and increment the corresponding index in the `freq` array, e.g  `for (i = 0; i < num; i++) freq[arr[i]]++;` Now just loop over `freq` and value at each index corresponds to how many times that number was seen (e.g. `if (freq[205] == 2)` then `205` appeared 2-times in `arr`.

Comment: Oh the testing sample in the question is ranged within 500 i think. Ok, i know what you mean now, I will try using that approach.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know if you get stuck. That will greatly simplify your logic. With the indexes in `freq` (originally initialized all zero) capturing the number of times the value in `arr` corresponding to the index in `freq` was seen, all you have to do is find the `max` in `freq` and take the *index* of first occurrence of that number as your answer.

Comment: Thank you David, I have tried your method it works perfectly fine. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad it helped. There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* in C. A frequency array is a very flexible solution for a number of counting, or greatest/least number of.... questions. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this part:

```c
while (i <= num) {                /*Add c1 if the value is the same*/
        if (arr[i+1] == a)
```

Here i should be less than `num-1`, as you get numbers, the index goes from 0 to num-1, normally `i<num` would be ok, but you have done `i+1` inside the loop so loop must only run from `0` to `num-2`. 
Though, from your logic it should be `arr[i]` not `arr[i+1]`

And this part

```c
        int a = arr[i];
        if (arr[i+1] == a) c1++;
```

Why would you assign a to value of arr[i] then again check with arr[i+1]? you only get c1 increasing with every duplicate value.
And this part at the end.

```c
i=j+1
```

which is causing the infinite loop.

This would probably solve your problem although it is not a good solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int  arr[20], num, result;
    printf("Input a number(1-20) and enter a series of numbers in ascending order: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Now enter the numbers");
    for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[k]);
    }
    int c1, c2, i, j;
    int temp = 0;
    j = 0;
    result=arr[0];
    c2 = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {                /*Add c1 if the value is the same*/
        int a = arr[i];
        c1=1;
        for(j=i+1;j<num;j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                c1+=1;
            }
        }
        if(c1>c2)
        {
            c2=c1;
            result=arr[i];
        }
        else if(c1==c2 && result>arr[i])
        {
            result=arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Number that appears the most time:%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Other than that, it has a better approach for your problem. make a struct of {int key, int count} then use it to store counts of all unique members in your array, then extract what you need.

Here is the code to what i was saying about, it might be hard to look into if you don't know about pointers & dynamic memory yet. but you'll get the logic.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct counts
    {
        int key;
        int count;
    };
    int * data;
    int num;
    printf("Enter the number of data:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    data=malloc(num*sizeof(int));

    int i,j;
    printf("Enter the data in order:");
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",data+i);
    }

    struct counts *table;
    int table_len=1;
    int flag;
    table=malloc(sizeof(struct counts));
    table[0].key=data[0];
    table[0].count=1;
    for (i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        flag=0;
        for(j=0;j<table_len;j++)
        {
            if (table[j].key==data[i])
            {
                flag=1;
                table[j].count+=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag==0)
        {
            table=realloc(table,++table_len* sizeof(struct counts));
            table[table_len-1].key=data[i];
            table[table_len-1].count=1;
        }
    }
    //if you want to see at the table
    printf("data\t\tcount\n");
    for(i=0;i<table_len;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d\t\t%d\n",table[i].key,table[i].count);
    }
    //now to extract the value
    int answer,count;
    answer=table[0].key;
    count=table[0].count;
    for(i=1;i<table_len;i++)
    {
        if(count>table[i].count)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(count<table[i].count)
        {
            answer=table[i].key;
            count=table[i].count;
        }
        else if(answer>table[i].key)
        {
            answer=table[i].key;
        }
    }
    printf("The number with highest frequency is: %d\n",answer);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: num-2 solved my problem for 6 elements in the array but it went to dead loop when the array has more than 6 elements. No issue with array that has 6/7 elements but starting to have dead loop with array that has 8 elements

Comment: your whole code is poorly written taht's why I gave you the alternative. ` i = j + 1` at the end of the for loop.. why is that there? it makes your loop infinite, you do i++ to increment it but then reassign i to j+1. removing that line will stop the loop but gives wrong answer, so look for your logic again. I'll see if I can find anything more

Comment: I have edited the answers to improve your logic, you had lots of unnecessary codes, still the code I gave at the end is far better and cleaner if you want to adopt to that strategy.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to make my code cleaner next time.

Comment: @JohnKhor, if this solved your problem, please accept the answer.  As far as I can tell, you've never accepted an answer, which is not fair on the folk who freely give their time to help you.